# Debugging Amplify for CORS

Tags: vue.js, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have an application with

- Front end : vue.js and AWS Amplify
- APIs with AWS API Gateway and Lambda
- DB : DynamoDB

I am able to access my get method through my browser, but through my vue application I am getting the error below

> Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev/product/?user=test' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

My javascript method to call the API is shown below

```
async created () {
let results = await getCurrentUser()
console.log(`Done: ${JSON.stringify(results.username)}`)
this.username = results.username

 try {
        const restOperation = get({ 
          apiName: this.apiName,
          path: this.path,
          options: {
            headers: {
                        Authorization: "test"
            },
            contentType:"application/json",
            queryParams: {
              user: this.username
            }}});
        const { body } = await restOperation.response;
        const json = await body.json();
        console.log('GET call succeeded: ', json);

         json.forEach(element => {
          let product= element
        
          this.productItems.push(product)
      
       })
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('GET call failed: ', error);
    }

}
```

I am not sure what is the problem and also not sure how to debug. Could someone help me out.

Cheers
Kris

Comment: Enabling CORS is a server-side concern. Your frontend code is irrelevant here. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: but how come it works when I access it from my browser?

Comment: Please have a good read of what I consider the [canonical _CORS_ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/283366). In short, it's not a cross-origin request when you open it directly. CORS only comes into play when you open one site and it tries to make an async request to another